# Bug tracing LaTeX page breaking penalties, adjusting rubber-length skips in KOMAscript

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, koma-script, widows-orphans, glue

I use KOMAscript's `scrbook` class. I am very nitpicking about clubs/widows. Interestingly, most clubs and widows predominantly occur on pages that have multiple flows, displayed math environments and or headings. I deem this remarkable, as all these elements with their stretchable vertical skips should provide LaTeX with sufficient flexibility to avoid clubs/widows.

At the moment a particular page drives me crazy which makes me assume that I have a conceptional misunderstanding of rubber lengths and the penalty mechanism (see image below). Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce a MWE. This problematic page is page 70.

Anyway, to get rid of the club I added the following lines to my preamble

```
\clubpenalty=9000           % Default:   150
\widowpenalty=9000          % Default:   150
\displaywidowpenalty=3000   % Default:    50
\setlength\floatsep       {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 2\p@}   % Default: 12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@ (scrsize10pt.clo)
\setlength\textfloatsep   {20\p@ \@plus 10\p@ \@minus 4\p@}  % Default: 20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@ (scrsize10pt.clo)
\setlength\intextsep      {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 2\p@}   % Default: 12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@ (scrsize10pt.clo)
\setlength\dblfloatsep    {12\p@ \@plus 6\p@ \@minus 2\p@}   % Default: 12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@ (scrsize10pt.clo)
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 10\p@ \@minus 4\p@}  % Default: 20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@ (scrsize10pt.clo)
```

But nothing changed. If I do the math correctly, I allowed a surplus of 4pt (`\floatsep`) and 8pt (`\textfloatsep`) of additional stretchable skips. That alone (12pt in total) should already be sufficient such that LaTeX waives the club at the bottom of the page.

It seems that LaTeX considers a club still less bad than stretching a rubber length. Is stretching/shrinking of a rubber length also penalized? If yes, by which amount?

Only, if I set `\clubpenalty=10000`, i.e. to "infinite", the club vanishes.
However, somewhere I read that setting infinity is not a wise choice, because LaTeX may select an very ugly solution, if it encounters several equally bad solutions.

Is there a way, to backtrace the penalty calculations during compulation and log the current values?

*PS:* Quite differently, I wonder if my re-definitions of penalties and lengths are "KOMA-compliant". I know, that KOMA has its own interface for many aspects, e.g. to set fonts or alter captions. Hence, I also consider the chance that my redefinition are simply ignored.

**The balky page with a club at the end:**
[image: Page with a club despite two floats and a heading]

Comment: Imho tex will not take the stretchable space into account when deciding about a page break, it will only use it later to fill up the empty space. You can trace the calculations with `\tracingpages=1`.

Comment: Not quite what you ask for but Frank's widows-and-orphans package can help adjusting these things or at least warning when they occur.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After reading chapter 6 and 12 to 15 of "The TeXbook", I would conclude, you're only partially right. TeX takes vertical glue into account when deciding about a page break, but not for "inserts" which is TeX' term for floats. Vertical glue is considered but only for paragraphs. I started to write an answer below, which is probably only partially correct.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER: This answer is written by a TeX noob and should be considered with care**

The information here is based on "The TeXbook" and "The LaTeX 2e Sources" plus what I concluded from the debug output that is enabled by `\tracepages=1`.

To understand how TeX decides about a page break, the following terms are important.

*Badness*: The badness *b* of a page layout (or more precisely, a list of vertical boxes) is "100 times the cube of the ratio by which the glue [...] must stretch or shrink to make an [box] of the required size." Originally, this definition is given for horizontal boxes and lines of paragraphs (see, ch. 14, p. 97, The TeXbook), but "vertical badness is computed by the same rules as horizontal badness" (ch. 15, p. 111, The TeXbook).

*Penalty*: The penalty *p* is an integer value associated with a breakpoint. For example, it is zero for breaking a page between paragraphs or—using the example from above—equals `\clubpenalty`, if the page break would result in a club.

*Insert penalty*: An insert penality *q* is a special kind of penalty that is associated with the splitting of inserts. Inserts are TeX' term for any vertical box that is placed out-of-order. LaTeX only knows floats and footnotes which are implemented on top of TeX' inserts. In TeX, inserts can split across pages, but in LaTeX only footnotes can split while ordinary floats are implemented as unbreakable. The penalty for splitting a footnote is parametrized by `\floatingpenalty`.

*Cost*: The cost *c* is the overall cost of breaking a page at a particular point and TeX tries to minimize the cost of a page when deciding for the best break point. The cost is calculated typically calculated as

> *c = b + p + q*

with badness *b*, penalty *p* and insert penalty *q* as defined above. I wrote "typically", because the true formula is a little bit more involved and defined in a case-by-case style, do deal special cases when one of the values is infinite (see ch. 15, p. 111, The TeXbook).

**Observation/Conjecture 1**: TeX indeed considers the stretchable part of vertical glue, when calculating the costs of a page break, which is the *b*-component (badness component). If there is sufficient stretchability such that the badness of a streched stack of vertical boxes is smaller than the penalty *p* of a club, then TeX should decide against the club and stretch the content of the page.

More definitions:

*Goal height*: The goal height *g* is the desired height of a page that needs to be filled by a list of vertical boxes. For a page without inserts, *g* equals `\textheight`.

*Page total*: The page total *t* is the height of all vertical boxes on a page and also has a shrinking/stretching component (which results from the stretching/shrinking component of the individual vertical boxes).

To construct a page, TeX successively adds more vertical boxes to the page. In each step, TeX calculates the cost *c* according to the formula above. TeX stops when the page total *t* is larger than the goal height *g*, even if *t* is shrunk to its minimum, i.e. squeezed as much content as possible onto the page. Then TeX selects the set of vertical boxes from the step that yields the lowest costs.

However, something interesting happens, if inserts (aka LaTeX floats) come into the play. Inserts are not added to the list of vertical boxes and increase the page total *t*, but the natural height of inserts are subtracted from the page goal *g*. In other words, TeX tries to fill a smaller page (reduced by the space occupied by the inserts).

Let's have a look at the debug output for the depicted page above. Remember we set `\clubpenalty=9000` and `\widowpenalty=9000` and in this case the page height equals  `\textheight = 582.19865pt`:

```
%% goal height=582.19865, max depth=5.5
%% goal height=381.98903, max depth=5.5
%% goal height=173.92876, max depth=5.5
% t=0.0 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=40.64388 plus 1.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=56.96384 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=9100 c=100000#
% t=73.2838 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=73.2838 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=73.2838 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=73.2838 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=89.60376 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=105.92372 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=122.24368 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=138.56364 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=9000 c=100000#
% t=154.8836 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=171.20357 plus 3.93948 g=173.92876 b=33 p=9000 c=9033#
% t=187.52353 plus 3.93948 g=173.92876 b=* p=0 c=*
```

For normal pages (without inserts) there is only a single top line that starts with a double percentage (`%%`). But here we have two inserts at the top of the page, that together reduce the goal height down to 173.92876pt.

Then TeX successively adds "normal" lines to the remaining page which can be confirmed by increasing *t* values. Please note, that the page total *t* has flexibility, but the only flexibility (the plus-part) stems from the header ("4.2.1 Registration", in the image above) and the todo-box. There is no flexibility between lines of the same paragraph.

The forth from last line, shows a penalty value *p = 9000*. This is the penalty of the widow, if the page was broken before "and output to the newly" (cp. image above).

The third from last line, shows a zero penalty again, because the first paraph is completed. This would create a page break after "the newly registered party" (cp. image above).

The second from last line, shows again a penalty value *p = 9000*. This is the penalty of the club, that we want to get rid of.

The last line shows *b=* p=0 c=**. This is TeX' way to tell that it is impossible to get a an additional line onto the page, i.e. the page total *t* is larger than the page goal *g*.

The interesting lines are

```
% t=154.8836 plus 2.93948 g=173.92876 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=171.20357 plus 3.93948 g=173.92876 b=33 p=9000 c=9033#
```

We would like to avoid the club. Despite the fact that a club has a penalty of 9000, the calculated costs are 9033 which is still smaller than the costs for a page break after the fist paragraph. Why? Let's do the math.

The page goal equals 173.92876pt. If only the first paragraph is put onto the page, the page total (i.e. natural height) is 154.8836pt. This results into a delta of 19.04616pt of missing content. The allowed stretchability is 2.93948pt. (Remember, this is only the stretchability of the section heading.) The results into a badness of 100*(19.04616pt/2.93948pt)^3 = 27,198. TeX cuts off this value at 10,000 and this is what we see in the first line.

Doing the same math for the second line, we can confirm 100*( (173.92876pt-171.20357pt)/3.93948pt)^3 = 33 for the badness. Together with the club penalty, we get 9033 of total costs. Please note, that we have a little bit more stretchability, too, namely 3.93948pt, because of the inter-paragraph stretchability.

**Conclusion:** TeX considers vertical stretchability when computing the costs of a page break, but ignores inserts.

This leads to the natural question for what the parameters `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep` and `\intextsep` are good for, if at all. After some digging in the LaTeX source code it seems, that they are only used by LaTeX (and not by TeX). If the page is ejected, TeX calls the output routine, that is also used to print page numbers and such things. LaTeX hooks into this routine and there the vertical glue of inserts/floats is considered (cp. Chapter 65, The LaTeX 2e Source).

**Personal remark:** Against my natural intuition, the inserts (floats) do not increase the flexibility of page, but actually decreases it, because the page goal value is decreased. On top, this approach is very inconsistent with the output routine, because there the additional glue is considered.