# LaTeX floats do not increase vertical stretchability nor the page total (t), but reduces the goal height (h). Why? And how to change?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, widows-orphans, badness

**Foreword**

This question is a follow up question of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500632/47156). More precisely, I was able to trace the problem down to its root, especially I was able to produce three MWE that illustrate the problem. However, I was not sure if it would be better to completely rewrite the [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500632/47156) (and thereby making the comments below the question incoherently) or state a new question. I decided for the latter. You do not need to read the original question, this one is self-contained. (Sorry, for the long post, but the problem is difficult to explain.)

**The problem**

I am very nitpicking about clubs/widows. Interestingly, most clubs and widows predominantly occur on pages that have multiple floats. This is remarkable, as floats with their stretchable vertical skips above and below should actually provide LaTeX with additional flexibility to avoid clubs/widows. However, I had to learn that quite the opposite happens, i.e. floats make it harder for TeX page breaking algorithm to find a good page break. I wonder

1. why it has been implemented this way, and
2. if there is a fix?

**The 1st MWE**

Please note, that this MWE *does not* use floats but there are "static" vertical boxes at the top of the page, that occupy the same space as the eventual floats in the 3rd MWE. I'd like to stress, that the stretchable skips `\floatsep` and `\textfloatsep` are hard-coded at the same positions as they would be for actual floats. Also, the line `\clubpenalty=150` is not required (because 150 is the default), but this way the MWEs are easier to compare.

I recommend to compile the following MWEs with plain latex (not pdflatex), to keep the log files concise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\clubpenalty=150
\flushbottom
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.05}
\nofiles
\tracingpages=1

\begin{document}

\hrule
\vskip 75pt
\centerline{First float}
\vskip 100pt
\hrule
\vskip\floatsep
\hrule
\vskip 75pt
\centerline{Second float}
\vskip 100pt
\hrule
\vskip\textfloatsep

This paragraph is simply meant to be filler in order to illustrate the problem.
We deliberately did not use the more common ``Lore ipsum'' to not confuse \TeX\ hyphenation mechanism.
With this minimal working example (MWE) we want to pin down a problem, when \TeX/\LaTeXe\ calculates the badness of a page.
It seems that the additional vertical flexibility that is provided by floats are not considered.

The text height equals \the\textheight, the baseline skip equals \the\baselineskip, the separation between the last top float or the first bottom float and the text equals \the\textfloatsep, the separation between an in-text float and the surrounding text equals \the\intextsep, and the separation between consecutive floats equals \the\floatsep.

To this end, we need at least two paragraphs that both are at least four lines long.
Four lines are the minimum to split a paragraph across pages without creating a club or widow.
Unfortunately, we run out of ideas what we could write to fill the remaining lines.
Maybe a quote from literature is our rescue: ``Be or not to be, that is the question''.
Yes, this is enough.
\end{document}
```

The result yields an unpleasant club (single 1st line of 3rd paragraph) at the end of the page.

[image: Illustration of 1st MWE]

**The 2nd MWE**

In this MWE the penalty for clubs is increased, but otherwise it is the same as the first MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\clubpenalty=2000
\flushbottom
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.05}
\nofiles
\tracingpages=1

\begin{document}

\hrule
\vskip 75pt
\centerline{First float}
\vskip 100pt
\hrule
\vskip\floatsep
\hrule
\vskip 75pt
\centerline{Second float}
\vskip 100pt
\hrule
\vskip\textfloatsep

This paragraph is simply meant to be filler in order to illustrate the problem.
We deliberately did not use the more common ``Lore ipsum'' to not confuse \TeX\ hyphenation mechanism.
With this minimal working example (MWE) we want to pin down a problem, when \TeX/\LaTeXe\ calculates the badness of a page.
It seems that the additional vertical flexibility that is provided by floats are not considered.

The text height equals \the\textheight, the baseline skip equals \the\baselineskip, the separation between the last top float or the first bottom float and the text equals \the\textfloatsep, the separation between an in-text float and the surrounding text equals \the\intextsep, and the separation between consecutive floats equals \the\floatsep.

To this end, we need at least two paragraphs that both are at least four lines long.
Four lines are the minimum to split a paragraph across pages without creating a club or widow.
Unfortunately, we run out of ideas what we could write to fill the remaining lines.
Maybe a quote from literature is our rescue: ``Be or not to be, that is the question''.
Yes, this is enough.
\end{document}
```

The club has disappeared and the additional blank space has been uniformly distributed over the stretchable skips.

[image: Illustration of 2nd MWE]

**The 3rd MWE**

This MWE actually uses the "correct" floats. Please note, that the vertical skips `\floatsep` and `\textfloatsep` *are not* part of the floats themselves, because they fall *between* floats and are part of the float definition. We stress that `\clubpenality` keeps the high value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\clubpenalty=2000
\flushbottom
\renewcommand\topfraction{.9}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.05}
\nofiles
\tracingpages=1

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\hrule
\vskip 75pt
\centerline{First float}
\vskip 100pt
\hrule
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
\hrule
\vskip 75pt
\centerline{Second float}
\vskip 100pt
\hrule
\end{figure}

This paragraph is simply meant to be filler in order to illustrate the problem.
We deliberately did not use the more common ``Lore ipsum'' to not confuse \TeX\ hyphenation mechanism.
With this minimal working example (MWE) we want to pin down a problem, when \TeX/\LaTeXe\ calculates the badness of a page.
It seems that the additional vertical flexibility that is provided by floats are not considered.

The text height equals \the\textheight, the baseline skip equals \the\baselineskip, the separation between the last top float or the first bottom float and the text equals \the\textfloatsep, the separation between an in-text float and the surrounding text equals \the\intextsep, and the separation between consecutive floats equals \the\floatsep.

To this end, we need at least two paragraphs that both are at least four lines long.
Four lines are the minimum to split a paragraph across pages without creating a club or widow.
Unfortunately, we run out of ideas what we could write to fill the remaining lines.
Maybe a quote from literature is our rescue: ``Be or not to be, that is the question''.
Yes, this is enough.
\end{document}
```

Surprisingly, the club has reappeared.

[image: Illustration of the 3rd MWE]

**The page breaking algorithm**

To understand how TeX decides about a page break, the following terms are important.

*Badness*: The badness *b* of a page layout (or more precisely, a list of vertical boxes) is "100 times the cube of the ratio by which the glue [...] must stretch or shrink to make an [box] of the required size." Originally, this definition is given for horizontal boxes and lines of paragraphs (see, ch. 14, p. 97, The TeXbook), but "vertical badness is computed by the same rules as horizontal badness" (ch. 15, p. 111, The TeXbook).

*Penalty*: The penalty *p* is an integer value associated with a breakpoint. For example, it is zero for breaking a page between paragraphs or—using the example from above—equals `\clubpenalty`, if the page break would result in a club.

*Insert penalty*: An insert penalty *q* is a special kind of penalty and unimportant here

*Cost*: The cost *c* is the overall cost of breaking a page at a particular point and TeX tries to minimize the cost of a page when deciding for the best break point. The cost is calculated typically calculated as

> *c = b + p + q*

with badness *b*, penalty *p* and insert penalty *q* as defined above. I wrote "typically", because the true formula is a little bit more involved and defined in a case-by-case style, do deal with special cases when one of the values is infinite (see ch. 15, p. 111, The TeXbook).

*Goal height*: The goal height *g* is the desired height of a page that needs to be filled by a list of vertical boxes. Typically, *g* equals `\textheight`.

*Page total*: The page total *t* is the height of all vertical boxes on a page and also has a shrinking/stretching component (which results from the stretching/shrinking component of the individual vertical boxes).

To construct a page, TeX successively adds more vertical boxes to the page. In each step, TeX calculates the cost *c* according to the formula above. TeX stops when the page total *t* is larger than the goal height *g*, even if *t* is shrunk to its minimum, i.e. squeezed as much content as possible onto the page. Then, TeX selects the set of vertical boxes from the step that yields the lowest costs.

**Interpretation of the log files**

*The 1st log file*

Now, lets have a look at the log file of the 1st MWE (using hardcoded "floats" and `\clubpenalty=150`):

```
%% goal height=550.0, max depth=5.0
% t=0.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=10.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=91.94444 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=192.34444 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=204.74443 plus 2.0 minus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=286.68887 plus 2.0 minus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=387.08887 plus 2.0 minus 2.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=414.03331 plus 5.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=150 c=100000#
% t=426.03331 plus 5.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
...
% t=534.03331 plus 6.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=1881 p=0 c=1881#
% t=546.03331 plus 7.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=18 p=150 c=168#
% t=558.03331 plus 7.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=* p=0 c=*
```

The goal height *g* equals 550pt, because this is `\textheight`. In the beginning, the page total *t* rapidly increases to 414.03331pt, because of the two top "floats". From there on, the page total increases in steps of 12pt, because this is the baseline skip for a 10pt font. Please note, that the page total *t* has has already gained plus 5.0pt minus 6.0pt strechability/shrinkability, because of `\textfloatsep` and `\floatsep`.

The last three lines are important. If the page break was placed after the end of the second paragraph, this would cost 1881, due to a high badness despite the fact that the penalty is zero. Let's do the math: The goal height equals 550pt, but the current page total is only 534.03331. This yields a delta of 15.96669pt of missing content and we have plus 6pt of stretchability. This gives the reported 100*(15.96660pt/6pt)^3 = 1884 badness.

If the page break was placed after the first line of the paragraph, this would only result into a badness of only 18 (using the same formula). Hence, even penalizing the club by 150, gives better total costs and TeX decides to accept the club.

The last line with *b=* and c=** only says that it is impossible to squeeze another line onto the page.

*The 2nd log file*

The previous example also tells us that penalizing a club by more than 1881-168 = 1713 should be sufficient to avoid the club. (This is the reason why the 2nd MWE uses `\clubpenalty=2000`. As expected, the log file gives

```
% t=534.03331 plus 6.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=1881 p=0 c=1881#
% t=546.03331 plus 7.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=18 p=2000 c=2018
% t=558.03331 plus 7.0 minus 6.0 g=550.0 b=* p=0 c=*
```

The higher penalty increases the total costs to 2018 and TeX decides to place the page break after the second paragraph.

*The 3rd log file*

Using actual floats as in the 3rd example causes an unexpected observation:

```
%% goal height=152.51114, max depth=5.0
% t=0.0 g=152.51114 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=10.0 g=152.51114 b=10000 p=2000 c=100000#
% t=22.0 g=152.51114 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
...
% t=130.0 plus 1.0 g=152.51114 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=142.0 plus 2.0 g=152.51114 b=10000 p=2000 c=100000#
% t=154.0 plus 2.0 g=152.51114 b=* p=0 c=*
```

**The goal height decreased to roughly 152pt which is the page height minus the space occupied by the floats. More importantly, the page total lost its strechability**, because `\textfloatsep` and `\floatsep` are not part of it. This give an incredibly high badness in the last-but-one line, because the denominator of the fraction is only 2pt instead of 7pt.

**Concluding Remarks**

I know, I could set `\clubpenalty=10000` to completely forbid clubs. In this case TeX calculates the cost of a page differently. However, using in "infinite" value for `\clubpenalty` may cause problems elsewhere.

Interestingly, if `\clubpenalty=10000` was set and TeX was forced to break the page after the second paragraph, the output routine (not presented here) takes the stretchability of `\textfloatsep` and `\floatsep` into account again. I deem this very inconsistent.

Comment: the tex-the-program page breaking that you are tracing there can not see or use the stretch space from \floatsep that is added by latex within the output routine while re-inserting the float boxes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have already concluded that from my debugging. The question is rather why is it implemented this way and can this be changed? I deem it a rather strange approach to remove the floats from the total page height and thereby "hiding away" the stretchability from the page breaking algorithm and later re-inserting the floats during the output routine.

Comment: removing the floats from the main document flow is the primary aim of the mechanism your example with in-place boxes and glues isn't comparable as you know in advance where they will be. You might hope for a different algorithm but the current algorithm is what it is

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I correctly understood the TeXbook, TeX has already a mechanism for "floats". They are called "inserts" which are created by a family of commands `\topinsert` and friends. TeX' and LaTeX' footnotes seem to be implemented on top of it, but LaTeX' floats are not. (If I'm right.) If TeX takes an insert from the stack of current contributions to the current page, the page total is increased. Also TeX' inserts are breakable. Otherwise the special penalty *q* would not make sense. Hence, I wonder why are LaTeX' floats not implemented on top of inserts, but re-invent the wheel?

Comment: latex floats have many features not available in \insert notably the whole `[htbp]` positioning control. I am not sure what answer can possibly be given to this question other than a note that your observation is correct.

Comment: Then the answer is quite easy. With respect to question 1: LaTeX floats are not implemented on top of TeX' inserts to enable to `[htbp]` positioning control. As a side-effect TeX' page breaking algorithm cannot utilize their provided flexibility. With respect to question 2: There is no easy fix to this drawback as the root cause lays deep in the LaTeX sources.

Comment: feel free to self answer